# Cell take colour from neighbour automatically

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-formatting, cell-formatting

I have a table of "top tippers". Names in Row G and tip amounts in Row H. I wanted to conditionally format the entire table so the top tipper is gold and the lowest tipper is white, going down in a color scale.
Simple enough with the numbers column using the built in Conditional Formatting, but I want each cell in the names column to match the cell color of the cell to the right of it. It's not as simple as just choosing the color for each cell because the Top Tipper will change every time a big tip comes in. (And it might become rather a long list!)

At the moment the names column is just white and the numbers column is doing the scale beautifully. Any ideas?
Happy to do it manually whilst I'm inputting data if there's an easy shortcut that doesn't involve changing the color of each individual cell.

The table in question:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Anna, welcome!  You say that you already have an exisitng conditional formatting (CF) rule that is colouring the numbers column exactly the way you want?

If so, go in and edit that rule, changing the range for the rule (at the top) to include column G.  So if it currently says: H2:H, change that to G2:H.

Then, in your formula, where the cell you reference is perhaps H2, change that to $H2.

This will make your CF formula apply the formatting (colour shading) to both columns, but based solely on the number value in column H.

Let us know if this works.  If not, please add your current CF formula to your question, and indicate the first cell of your number column.  Is it H2?